# Why is my 'NOT IN ' query not returning correct data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `AvailableStocks` and `tblTranslateGeneric`
We could say that `AvailableStocks` entries are replication of `tblTranslateGeneric` (but not exatly, because there's some reason (processes) why entries didn't get through `AvailableStocks`)

This table can contain up to 12,xxx of entries.
Now I want to get the column values (idvehicle) of all that didn't make it through final table.
Simply get all the `idvehicle` which is available on `tblTranslateGeneric` but not available on  `AvailableStocks`.

I thought of making a temporary table first then inserting all the values. Then I'll make a not exist clause , but it's not working. All it returns is all the data in `AvailableStocks`

```
CREATE TABLE #idirect (idvehicle int)
INSERT INTO #idirect
SELECT idvehicle from tblavailablestocks with(nolock) WHERE idauctionevent = 106484 

CREATE TABLE #translate (idvehicle int)
INSERT INTO #translate
SELECT idvehicle from tblTranslateGeneric with(nolock) WHERE idauctionevent = 106484 and IDRequest =28782700

SELECT COUNT (*) FROM #translate --returns 1379
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM #idirect   -- returns 1374


SELECT idvehicle FROM #translate WHERE idvehicle not in(SELECT * FROM #idirect) -- this returns 1379d records instead of 5 records
```

my expected returns should be the IDVehicle not available on `AvailableStocks`table but available to `tblTranslateGeneric`

Sample Datas :

```
idvehicle
1993429875
1993429876
1993429877
1993430466
1993430467
1993430468
1993429974
1993429975
1993429976
1993429755
```

Comment: is that really the query you used ?  there are syntax error.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: As a best practice you should list the columns your are inserting into in our insert statement.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What does `select count(*) from #Inserted where idvehicle is null` return?

Comment: You select all entries in table1 except for the few AvailableStocks with idevent = 106464. Is this your intention? You don't mention this event ID restriction anywhere, and this restriction makes it very likely to select loads of rows from table1, because you dismiss only very few.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. We don't know what data you want to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```sql
SELECT IDVehicle
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AvailableStocks t2
                  WHERE t2.IDVehicle = t1.IDVehicle);
```

Comment: It's not working instead it returns a large number results.

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello `Simply get all the idvehicle which is available on Table1 but not available on AvailableStocks` That is exact what the query in this answer does, maybe you did not explain correct what you want ?

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello I don't think you need that intermediate temp table.  Just use an exists query which directly checks against `AvailableStocks`, q.v. my updated answer above.

Comment: @john you also need to add `and idevent = 106464` to the above queries.